# Why is userData an empty array even after fetching and awaiting the data?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

```
function App() {
  const [userData, setData] = useState([]);

const getData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const data = await res.json();
    setData(data);
    console.log(userData);
  };
 

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={getData}>get data</button>
      
      <div>
        {userData?.map((user) => {
          return (
            <p key={user.id}>
              {user.name} {user.email}
            </p>
          );
        })}
       
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried to fetch the data and then store it in my state variable `userData`. Upon console logging `userData`, it should show the data fetched as per my knowledge. I know that `await` stops further execution until the promise returned by the Fetch Api is either resolved or rejected. In that case, `userData` should be updated using `setData`. But why is `userData` still an empty array upon logging, even after awaiting the result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: `setData(data)` will update the `userData` on the next render. As long as you're in the scope of the `getData` function `userData` will hold the old value. If you want to use the data immediately change `console.log(userData)` into `console.log(data)`. Or move the `console.log()` inside the render function or a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState will update the variable on the next rerender.

Try this:

```
function App() {
  const [userData, setData] = useState([]);

const getData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const data = await res.json();
    setData(data);
    
  };
  console.log(userData);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={getData}>get data</button>
      
      <div>
        {userData?.map((user) => {
          return (
            <p key={user.id}>
              {user.name} {user.email}
            </p>
          );
        })}
       
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```